# Reading value from JSON - help writing the logic

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have the `JSON` in the format of

```
{"index":"0","name":"jemmy","age":"2"}
```

I need to extract the values stored and save it; I have done the following, but it doesn't work

> - Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>     'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString objectForKey:]:
>     unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6671a10'

my code

```
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [request responseHeaders];
    SBJsonParser *parser = [SBJsonParser new];     
    id content = [responseString JSONValue];
    NSDictionary *dealDictionary = content;
    NSArray *array = [dealDictionary allKeys];
    for (NSString *str in array)
    {
        NSDictionary *childDictionary = [dealDictionary objectForKey:str];
        NSLog(@"%@ ",[childDictionary objectForKey:@"name"]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may not understand how to use SBJSON, maybe a quick read through the [documentation](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/api/3.0/) would be useful. First, you need to actually use the parser that you create:

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [SBJsonParser new];
NSDictionary *content = [parser objectWithString:[request responseString]];
```

Secondly, you can traverse your dictionary slightly easier as such:

```
NSEnumerator *enum = [content keyEnumerator];
id key;
while (key = [enum nextObject]) {
    NSLog(@"key %@ and object %@",key,[content objectForKey:key]);
}
```

Comment: for some reason it starts to read from `"name":"jemmy"` and then reads `"index":"0"`. Why is this? I need it to read it in an order. How can i achieve this?

Comment: @shajem Dictionaries are not ordered. If you need a specific value, just request it with `[content objectForKey:@"index"]`